# How to identify the virus or process

Tags: process, macos-catalina, virus

I have noted unauthorized access to my router (default gateway) from my PC (Catalina iMac).
I am investigating this because we have several Mac PCs that are having the same behavior.
I would like to identify the virus or process that is causing this unauthorized access and remove it.

We scanned our PC with Virus Buster and Avast Antivirus, but it did not detect any viruses...

To investigate, I took tcpdump log of my PC.
And I confirmed packets accessing the router.
For several minutes after starting up the PC, the following suspicious behavior is observed.

1. Lots of DNS queries I don't recognize.
   I don't remember accessing them.

```
myspace.com, qq.com, baidu.com, weebly.com, mail.ru, odnoklassniki.ru, aol.com, ebay.com, alibaba.com etc.
```

2. Lots of access to various ports.

```
21, 22, 23, 53, 81, 111, 135, 139, 192, 427, 443, 445, 515, 548, 554, 631, 873, 1433, 1688, 1801, 1900, 1980, 1990, 2105, 2323, 2869, 3000, 3283, 3306, 3389, 3910, 4070, 4071, 5000, 5001, 5040, 5060, 5094, 5357, 5431, 5555, 5800, 5900, 5916, 5985, 6668, 7547, 7676, 7680, 7777, 8000, 8001, 8002, 8008, 8009, 8080, 8081, 8082, 8089, 8090, 8099, 8181, 8182, 8291, 8443, 8728, 8888, 9080, 9100, 9101, 9112, 9220, 9295, 9999, 10001, 10243, 12323, 15500, 16992, 16993, 17500, 18181, 20005, 30005, 30102, 37215, 37777, 41800, 41941, 44401, 47001, 47546, 49000, 49152, 49153, 49200, 49443, 49667, 52869, 52881, 53048, 55442, 55443, 57621, 59777, 60000, 62078
```

3. Lots of http, https access

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
GET /admin HTTP/1.1
GET /AvastUniqueURL HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/a2/out.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/ajaxmail HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/arr/index.shtml HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/at3/out.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/atc/out.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/atx/out.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/auth HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/bbs/postlist.pl HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/bbs/postshow.pl HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/bp_revision.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/br5.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/click.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/clicks.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/crtr/out.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/fg.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/findweather/hdfForecast HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/frame_html HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/getattach HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/hotspotlogin.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/hslogin.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/ib/301_start.pl HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/index HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/index.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/krcgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/krcgistart HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/link HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/login HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/login.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/logout HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/mainmenu.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/mainsrch HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/msglist HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/navega HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/openwebmail/openwebmail-main.pl HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/out.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/passremind HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/rbaccess/rbcgi3m01 HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/rbaccess/rbunxcgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/readmsg HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/rshop.pl HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/search.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/spcnweb HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/sse.dll HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/start HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/te/o.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/tjcgi1 HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/top/out HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/traffic/process.fcgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/verify.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/webproc HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/webproc?getpage=/../../etc/passwd&var:language=en_us&var:page=* HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/webproc?getpage=/etc/shadow HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/webproc?getpage=/etc/shadow&errorpage=html/main.html&var:language=en_us&var:menu=setup&var:page=wizard HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
GET /cgi-bin/wingame.pl HTTP/1.1
GET /das/cgi-bin/session.cgi HTTP/1.1
GET /dd.xml HTTP/1.1
GET /fcgi-bin/dispatch.fcgi HTTP/1.1
GET /fcgi-bin/performance.fcgi HTTP/1.1
GET /Frontend HTTP/1.1
GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1
GET /L3F.xml HTTP/1.1
GET /login.html HTTP/1.1
GET /menu.html?images/ HTTP/1.1
GET /picsdesc.xml HTTP/1.1
GET /redir/cgi-bin/ajaxmail HTTP/1.1
GET /rom-0 HTTP/1.1
GET /rootDesc.xml HTTP/1.1
GET /ssdp/device-desc.xml HTTP/1.1
GET /upnp/dev/a266dba0-8baa-3406-a010-2db481ceabf3/desc HTTP/1.1
GET /WANCfg.xml HTTP/1.1
GET /WANIPCn.xml HTTP/1.1
GET /WANIPCn.xml HTTP/1.1 )
POST /ctl/CmnIfCfg HTTP/1.1
POST /ctl/IPConn HTTP/1.1
POST /uuid:0cd2a2e0-68c2-a366-b2f1-8d93ddce634b/WANIPConnection:1 HTTP/1.1
```

If you have any information about viruses that behave this way, etc., it would be helpful.
Also, please reply me know if there is any other information you need in order to identify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found out that it was caused by the Wi-Fi Inspector feature of Avast Antivirus!
The pattern of tcpdump log when the Wi-Fi Inspector button is clicked is almost same.